# Black 1px line between two elements

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to remove this vertical line between two colored elements(red and green). Whats wrong with my code? or its color shadow or what i dont understand

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 0;
}

div li {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
}

li:first-child {
  width: 33.3%;
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 33.3%;
  background-color: green;
}

li:last-child {
  width: 33.3%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not see a vertical line between any of your elements.

Comment: your widths add up to 99.9%, so there's your black line: the missing 0.1%. try making one of those `<li>` with 33.4% instead

Comment: @MarcB I had considered this. If that were the case though, why would the line be black, and why would it be between the first and second element - not at the end?

Comment: I screen capped the example and zoomed the hell out of it in Photoshop and see no black line. Optical illusion?

Comment: I try your code and change red li to blue. There is no black line when you change the color. So are you sure that its not only a phenomenon of human visual perception ?

Comment: Agree with j08691 - optical illusion, i've tried zooming too...

Comment: Definitely an optical illusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line is black because computers are "lazy" and combine colors by mediating the color value like C = (C1+C2)/2 when it should be C = ((sqr(C1) + sqrt(C2)/2)/2)^2. You understand why they are "lazy".

Watch this youtube video for more details. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw

And they combine because the browser pixels don't fit to your screens pixels.. at some point someone does some color combination.

Answer (score 0):

33.3% x 3 = 99.9%
I agree with the previous comments, set 33.4% one of them.