# Unidentified edge where two borders meet?

Tags: html, css, border

I have noticed when testing my page on my phone that the point where the two borders meet, an unidentified edge appears

[image: Borders meeting example one]

I have also tried having a larger border bottom on my *h1* element and a 0 border top for my *nav ul* element

[image: Borders meeting example two]

And look what happens if the background color of the body is the same color as the border

[image: Proof of border edge]

This issue also appears while testing on Google Chromes responsive developer tool.

This is my code for this question

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: yellow;
    background-color: blue;
    border:20px solid yellow;
    border-bottom: 10px solid yellow;
    margin: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border:20px solid yellow;
    border-top: 10px solid yellow;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

nav li {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: blue;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
    width: 67px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>
        SPACING
    </h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">MARGIN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BORDER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PADDING</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have disabled zoom by using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scable=no">` in the head of my html.

I have also tried increasing the border-bottom of my *h1* element by 1px and giving the *nav ul* element a margin-top of -1px which partially works, however this issue will still appear at differnt resolutions or orientation.

I am wondering if anybody knows why this happens and hopefully a solution.

Comment: this happens because of zoom, and thats normal thing

Comment: Did you look at my screen shots, my page does not zoom

Comment: Had forgot to mention in my question that I disabled the zoom in my html, by using viewport

Comment: Have you reset the zoom in the browser?

`View > Actual size`

Comment: i used the same thing like you 360x640 100%zoom and theres is no any line thats zoom problem with your browser not css problem

Comment: I am using Google responsive developer tool to emulate this issue, When testing on my phone I noticed this issue, it has nothing to do with zoom

Comment: look how it looks on my browser `https://sendvid.com/4zmys270`. im going to check this on my mobile browser

Comment: What browser did you use the 360 x 640 resolution with? Google Chromes developer tool is more accurate as I did not see this in firefox . remember I first noticed this on my phone so it is not a browser problem

Comment: Looks like a Chrome browser bug to me when in mobile mode. Just zooming in Chrome doesn't produce this effect, nor Firefox mobile.

Comment: This also appeared on my phone when using my default browser while testing

Comment: i tested it, theres a line on my mobile browser too... i dont know

Comment: Thank you for trying to help felixsturm

Comment: no problem, yea thats definitely browser color bug see whats going on when i change background-color `https://sendvid.com/tx21y0jn` there is something like shadow or take a look on this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048414/black-1px-line-between-two-elements` . "color bug"

Answer (score 4):

Try using this, see if that's what you need :
https://jsfiddle.net/1r7hp15c/3/

CSS:

```
body {
width: 100%;
background-color: blue;
}

h1 {
font-size: 35px;
text-align: center;
color: yellow;
background-color: blue;

margin: 2%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

 nav ul {

display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;

padding: 0;
margin: 0;

margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 2%;
background:blue;
}

nav li {
font-size: 15px;
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: blue;
color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
width: 67px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
color: yellow;
text-decoration: none;
}
div{
padding: 20px;
background: yellow;
}
nav{
padding: 20px;
background: yellow;
margin-top: -1px;
 }
```

HTML :

```
    <header>
<div>
    <h1>
        SPACING
    </h1>
 </div>   
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">MARGIN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BORDER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PADDING</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: dont use such big borders ,instead add to a container and add padding to it.
for your particular case, `margin-top :-1px` did the magic.

Comment: @lazyrabbit Please add some explanation.. What does it do and why? _(providing fish instead of teaching how to fish)_

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I applied it to my design and whilst testing it descovered that it is not a responsive solution as I was using a fixed width for my side borders and your solution displays these as the background so when the screen size gets smaller so does the width of the two side borders